# \makesavenoteenv to fix table footnotes doesn't work with minted package

Tags: tables, footnotes, minted

I finally thought I'd cracked the footnotes-in-tables problem, but importing my MWE into the main document revealed a clash with the minted package.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{footnote}
%\usepackage{minted}   <--------------- UNCOMMENT THIS TO TRIGGER ERROR

\makesavenoteenv{tabular}
\makesavenoteenv{table}

\newenvironment{aside}[1]%
{%
        \begin{tabular}{|l|}%
            \hline ASIDE (#1) \\ \hline%
}%
{%
            \\ \hline%
        \end{tabular}%
}

\begin{document}

Foo\footnote{foonote}

\begin{aside}{advanced}
    xxxzz\footnote{foobar} s
\end{aside}

Bar\footnote{barnote}

\end{document}
```

The above `\makesavenoteenv` trick is the only reasonable way I have found of allowing footnotes to behave "normally" in tables, but when `\usepackage{minted}` is uncommented, I get

```
[Loading MPS to PDF converter (version 2006.09.02).]
))) (./_minted-aside/default-pyg-prefix.pygstyle)
! Extra }, or forgotten \endgroup.
<argument> ...@finalstrut \strutbox }\fn@endnote }

l.23    xxxzz\footnote{foobar}
                             s
```

Can I make these play nicely together?

Comment: The `footnote` package has been unmaintained for several years and seems to be incompatible with several new packages.

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried [footnotehyper](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/footnotehyper) ?

This works for me

```
% needs shell-escape for minted
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{footnotehyper}
\usepackage{minted}%  DOES NOT TRIGGER ERROR IF USING footnotehyper

\makesavenoteenv{tabular}
\makesavenoteenv{table}

\newenvironment{aside}[1]%
{%
        \begin{tabular}{|l|}%
            \hline ASIDE (#1) \\ \hline%
}%
{%
            \\ \hline%
        \end{tabular}%
}

\begin{document}

Foo\footnote{foonote}

\begin{aside}{advanced}
    xxxzz\footnote{foobar} s
\end{aside}

Bar\footnote{barnote}

\end{document}
```

---

[image]

bottom of page:

[image]

Comment: side note: your OP does `\makesavenoteenv{table}` which is kept here. It is mentioned in `footnotehyper` doc that this leads to a clash with package `float`, if using `H` position specifier. It is safer to use explicitely `\begin{savenotes)...\end{savenotes}` in the document, or possibly patch `table` via some safer way (`etoolbox`?) than using the `footnote.sty`  `\makesavenoteenv` which has been kept as is in `footnotehyper.sty`.

Comment: this requires `footnotehyper v1.0 (2017/03/07)`, i.e. the one currently in TL2017 or the one from very mature TL2016, because earlier versions worked only in presence of hyperref.