# Roll my own footnote command for new environment based minipage/tabular/etc

Tags: environments, footnotes, data-structures

I thought I'd solved the footnotes-in-tables problem with `\makesavenoteenv` but [it interacts badly with the minted package](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/375350/makesavenoteenv-to-fix-table-footnotes-doesnt-work-with-minted-package) so I thought, since my problem is really "make footnotes work in my box environment", maybe I can create a new footnote command to queue up footnotes which can be added to the page when the environment ends.

```
\documentclass{article}

% let ASIDE_FOOTNOTES be an empty list

\newcommand\asidefootnote[1]%
{%
    \footnotemark{}%
    % add #1 to ASIDE_FOOTNOTES list
}

\newcommand\emitasidefootnotes%
{
    % where SIZE is the length of the ASIDE_FOOTNOTES list
    % \addtocounter{footnote}{-SIZE}

    % for each NOTE in ASIDE_FOOTNOTES
    % \footnotetext{NOTE}

    % let ASIDE_FOOTNOTES be an empty list
}

\newenvironment{aside}[1]
{
    \begin{minipage}{0.5\textwidth}
    ASIDE (#1) \par
}
{
    \end{minipage}
    \emitasidefootnotes
}

\begin{document}

Foo\footnote{foonote}

\begin{aside}{advanced}
    aaa\asidefootnote{foo aaa} bbb\asidefootnote{foo bbb}
\end{aside}

Bar\footnote{barnote}

\begin{aside}{advanced}
    xxx\asidefootnote{foo xxx} zzz\asidefootnote{foo zzz}
\end{aside}

Baz\footnote{baznote}

\end{document}
```

Basically, I need to turn the above comments into actual code.

1. The argument to `\asidefootnote` can be arbitray tex.
2. It needs to not interfere with other, normal footnotes. In the above example, footnotes 1 through 7 should appear together, in the natural order, at the bottom of the page.
3. It *doesn't* need to work recursively (an `aside` environment will never contain another `aside` environment, directly or indirectly, nor will it contain any other environment which uses this trick).

How do I implement this? (In other words, how do I add a chunk of tex to a list, pass the size of that list to `\addtocounter`, iterate over that list, and empty that list?)

Comment: I think people are misusing footnotes. :-(

Comment: Possibly related: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/314375/why-does-parbox-lose-footnotes/314531?s=10|0.3783#314531

Comment: @Johannes_B how?

Comment: maybe answer to https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/375350/makesavenoteenv-to-fix-table-footnotes-doesnt-work-with-minted-package solves your general problem too.

Answer (score 1):

This gets the job done, but it's a bit of a hack. I'll hold off on accepting my own answer in case someone posts a better, pure tex solution (but this should be considered a reference implementation).

I had `\asidefootnote` write its footnote text to a file, then `\emitasidefootnotes` calls a Perl script which reads that file and generates the footnotes with correct numbering.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mdframed}
\usepackage{xcolor}

% Taken from https://gist.github.com/w495/7328b76e76aee49657e0bd7a3b46c870
% This runs a bash command and prits the first line of its output into the
% document
\makeatletter
    \newcommand{\bashline@file@name}[1]{%
        /tmp/${USER}-${HOSTNAME}-\jobname-#1.tex%
    }
    \newread\bashline@file
    \newcommand{\bashline@command@one}[2][tmp]{%
        \immediate\write18{#2 > \bashline@file@name{#1}}
        \openin\bashline@file=\bashline@file@name{#1}
        % The group localizes the change to \endlinechar
        \bgroup
            \endlinechar=-1
            \read\bashline@file to \localline
            % Since everything in the group is local, 
            % we have to explicitly make the assignment global
            \global\let\bashline@result\localline
        \egroup
        \closein\bashline@file
        % Clean up after ourselves
        \immediate\write18{rm \bashline@file@name{#1}}
        \bashline@result
    }
    \newcommand{\bashline@command@many}[2][tmp]{%
        \immediate\write18{#2 > \bashline@file@name{#1}}
        \openin\bashline@file=\bashline@file@name{#1}
        % The group localizes the change to \endlinechar
        \newcount\linecnt
        \bgroup
            \endlinechar=-1
            \loop\unless\ifeof\bashline@file 
                \read\bashline@file to \localline%
                \localline
                \newline
            \repeat
        \egroup
        \closein\bashline@file
        % Clean up after ourselves
        \immediate\write18{rm \bashline@file@name{#1}}
    }
    \newcommand{\bashline}[2][tmp]{%
        \bashline@command@one[#1]{#2}%
    }
    \newcommand{\bashlines}[2][tmp]{%
        \bashline@command@many[#1]{#2}%
    }
\makeatother

% The \asidefootnote and \emitasidefootnotes commands
\def\asideinpfilename{aside.inp}
\def\asidetexfilename{aside.out}

\newwrite\asidefile
\immediate\openout\asidefile=\asideinpfilename
%\immediate\write\asidefile{ASIDES-START-HERE}

\newcommand{\asidefootnote}[1]%
{%
    \footnotemark{}%
    \immediate\write\asidefile{\unexpanded{#1}}%
}

\newcommand{\emitasidefootnotes}%
{%
    \immediate\closeout\asidefile%
    \bashline{perl bin/emit-aside-foonotes.pl '\asideinpfilename' '\asidetexfilename'}%
    \input{\asidetexfilename}%
    \immediate\openout\asidefile=\asideinpfilename%
}

\newenvironment{aside}[1]
{
    \mdfsetup{%
       middlelinecolor=red,
       middlelinewidth=2pt,
       backgroundcolor=red!5}
    \begin{mdframed}
    ASIDE (#1) \par
}
{
    \end{mdframed}
    \emitasidefootnotes
}

\begin{document}

Foo\footnote{foonote}

\begin{aside}{intermediate}
    aaa\asidefootnote{foo

    \begin{tabular}{|l|l|}
            \hline
            a & b \\ \hline
            c & d \\ \hline
    \end{tabular}}
    bbb\asidefootnote{foo bbb}
\end{aside}

Bar\footnote{barnote}

\begin{aside}{advanced}
    xxx\asidefootnote{foo xxx} zzz\asidefootnote{foo zzz}
\end{aside}

Baz\footnote{baznote}

\end{document}
```

The Perl script `bin/emit-aside-footnotes.pl` looks like this:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;

die "Needs arguments: infile outfile" if (2 != @ARGV);

my $in_name  = $ARGV[0];
my $out_name = $ARGV[1];

open (my $in,  "<", $in_name)  or die $!;
open (my $out, ">", $out_name) or die $!;

my @lines = <$in>;

my $n = @lines;

exit if (0 == $n);

print $out "\\addtocounter{footnote}{-$n}";

chomp and print $out "\\stepcounter{footnote}\\footnotetext{$_}"
foreach (@lines);
```

Result:

[image]

Note that `\immediate\write\asidefile{\unexpanded{#1}}` automatically writes a *single* line to the file even if `#1` contains multiple lines of tex, which makes the multi-line footnote 2 possible.